# Missing SetRepresentation() method in C# MongoDB.Driver 2.0.0-beta1

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm working with latest [C# driver for MongoDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/). I know it's beta now, but I think I'm doing some basic things.

What's my problem: I'm trying to set representation for my Id field to `ObjectId` instead of `string` like it is described in [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#representationserializationoptions):

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Entity>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

But I can not do that because method `SetRepresentation()` does not exist. And I can not find anything similar.

So I wonder, was this method removed? 
Is there any other way to set representation besides attributes? I can not use attributes because I don't have access to Entity class, I'm working with derived class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This method exists in version 1.9.2.235

Comment: I know, but why it is not there in 2.0.0? I'm using 2.0.0 for it's async capabilities.

Comment: Its interesting, they also removed [BsonRepresentation] attribute

Comment: See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/upgrading/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've spoken with the developer of the driver and he clarified this situation:

> We've brought all those options into the serializers themselves, so, in this case, you'll want to set the serializer. IdMemberMap.SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId)); //It's a string which will be represented as an ObjectId in the database.

Comment: thank you for posting this, they should really update their documentation!!

Answer (score 6):

this works for me (v2.2)

```
cm.MapIdMember(c => c.Id)
  .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
  .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
```

it's represent objectId in database (not string)

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56715ebddb6986202816e566"),
```